# Load different set of routes if user is on domain and different if not on domain

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to load a different set of domains at launch if a user is on a subdomain (test.example.com), versus being on a domain (example.com). However, my code keeps defaulting to the domainRoutes without the facility to allow the user to browse (as all the routes don't exist). How can I fix this?

```
const domainRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', loadChildren: './modules/main/main.module#MainModule' }
];

const subdomainRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', loadChildren: './modules/website/website.module#WebsiteModule' }
];

const isOnDomain = () => {
  const full = window.location.host;
  const parts = full.split('.');
  let result = true;
  if (parts[0] && parts[1] && parts[2]) {
    result = false;
  }
  return result;
};

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(isOnDomain() ? subdomainRoutes: domainRoutes),
  ],
  providers: [
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule {
}
```

Comment: It seems you forgot to call the `isOnDomain` function

Comment: It doesn't fix the problem

Comment: It also seems that if `isOnDomain()` is true then `domainRoutes` should be returned so you need to change the ternary. Could you debug or just put `console.log` into the function and tell me what are the values for both cases?

Comment: When on a subdomain, `isOnDomain()` it evaluates to false. Otherwise it returns true.

Comment: For `domain.com` your function returns true thus ternary returns `subdomainRoutes`. For `domain.com` the function returns false thus ternary returns `domainRoutes`